# dismissing presented UICameraPicker closes the current view

Tags: ios, objective-c

I present my view controller like so:

```
- (void) showImagePicker:(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType)source {
    [self dismissKeyboard];

    if(self.cameraImagePicker == nil) {
        self.cameraImagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    }

    self.cameraImagePicker.delegate = self;
    self.cameraImagePicker.allowsEditing = YES;
    self.cameraImagePicker.sourceType = source;
    //[self presentModalViewController:self.cameraImagePicker animated:YES];
    [self presentViewController:self.cameraImagePicker animated:NO completion:nil];
}
```

However, whenever I call `[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];` it not only closes the image picker, but also the view I was currently on.

How can I get the UIImagePickerController to close without also killing my current view?

**EDIT**

Here is my dismissing code.

```
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_main_queue();
dispatch_async(queue, ^{
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[[responseObject objectForKey:@"result"] objectForKey:@"image"]];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    self.displayPictureView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
    data = nil;
    [self.cameraImagePicker dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
});
```

and a console log.

```
Jul  3 14:36:45 Damons-iPhone kernel[0] <Debug>: AppleH4CamIn::power_on_hardware
Jul  3 14:36:46 Damons-iPhone kernel[0] <Debug>: AppleH4CamIn::ISP_SelectBestMIPIFrequencyIndex_gated - channel: 0, index: 0
Jul  3 14:36:50 Damons-iPhone com.apple.launchd[1] (com.apple.routined[4653]) <Notice>: (com.apple.routined) Idle-exit job was jettisoned. Will bypass throttle interval for next on-demand launch.
Jul  3 14:36:50 Damons-iPhone com.apple.launchd[1] (com.apple.routined[4653]) <Error>: (com.apple.routined) assertion failed: 11D201: launchd + 35933 [666E5F5B-36E7-3134-852E-A4BFEF07CD31]: 0x9
Jul  3 14:36:50 Damons-iPhone com.apple.launchd[1] (com.apple.mediaremoted[4652]) <Notice>: (com.apple.mediaremoted) Idle-exit job was jettisoned. Will bypass throttle interval for next on-demand launch.
Jul  3 14:36:50 Damons-iPhone com.apple.launchd[1] (com.apple.mediaremoted[4652]) <Error>: (com.apple.mediaremoted) assertion failed: 11D201: launchd + 35933 [666E5F5B-36E7-3134-852E-A4BFEF07CD31]: 0x9
Jul  3 14:36:50 Damons-iPhone com.apple.launchd[1] (com.apple.timed[4689]) <Notice>: (com.apple.timed) Idle-exit job was jettisoned. Will bypass throttle interval for next on-demand launch.
Jul  3 14:36:50 Damons-iPhone com.apple.launchd[1] (com.apple.timed[4689]) <Error>: (com.apple.timed) assertion failed: 11D201: launchd + 35933 [666E5F5B-36E7-3134-852E-A4BFEF07CD31]: 0x9
Jul  3 14:36:50 Damons-iPhone com.apple.launchd[1] (com.apple.networkd_privileged[4693]) <Notice>: (com.apple.networkd_privileged) Idle-exit job was jettisoned. Will bypass throttle interval for next on-demand launch.
Jul  3 14:36:50 Damons-iPhone com.apple.launchd[1] (com.apple.networkd_privileged[4693]) <Error>: (com.apple.networkd_privileged) assertion failed: 11D201: launchd + 35933 [666E5F5B-36E7-3134-852E-A4BFEF07CD31]: 0x9
Jul  3 14:36:50 Damons-iPhone com.apple.launchd[1] (com.apple.lsd[4692]) <Notice>: (com.apple.lsd) Idle-exit job was jettisoned. Will bypass throttle interval for next on-demand launch.
Jul  3 14:36:50 Damons-iPhone com.apple.launchd[1] (com.apple.lsd[4692]) <Error>: (com.apple.lsd) assertion failed: 11D201: launchd + 35933 [666E5F5B-36E7-3134-852E-A4BFEF07CD31]: 0x9
Jul  3 14:36:50 Damons-iPhone com.apple.launchd[1] (com.apple.securityd[4690]) <Notice>: (com.apple.securityd) Idle-exit job was jettisoned. Will bypass throttle interval for next on-demand launch.
Jul  3 14:36:50 Damons-iPhone com.apple.launchd[1] (com.apple.securityd[4690]) <Error>: (com.apple.securityd) assertion failed: 11D201: launchd + 35933 [666E5F5B-36E7-3134-852E-A4BFEF07CD31]: 0x9
Jul  3 14:36:50 Damons-iPhone ****[4687] <Warning>: Received memory warning.
Jul  3 14:36:50 Damons-iPhone com.apple.launchd[1] (com.apple.nsnetworkd[4694]) <Notice>: (com.apple.nsnetworkd) Idle-exit job was jettisoned. Will bypass throttle interval for next on-demand launch.
Jul  3 14:36:50 Damons-iPhone com.apple.launchd[1] (com.apple.nsnetworkd[4694]) <Error>: (com.apple.nsnetworkd) assertion failed: 11D201: launchd + 35933 [666E5F5B-36E7-3134-852E-A4BFEF07CD31]: 0x9
Jul  3 14:36:50 Damons-iPhone ****[4687] <Warning>: Received memory warning.
Jul  3 14:36:50 Damons-iPhone com.apple.launchd[1] (com.apple.nsnetworkd[4695]) <Notice>: (com.apple.nsnetworkd) Idle-exit job was jettisoned. Will bypass throttle interval for next on-demand launch.
Jul  3 14:36:50 Damons-iPhone com.apple.launchd[1] (com.apple.nsnetworkd[4695]) <Error>: (com.apple.nsnetworkd) assertion failed: 11D201: launchd + 35933 [666E5F5B-36E7-3134-852E-A4BFEF07CD31]: 0x9
Jul  3 14:36:50 Damons-iPhone com.apple.launchd[1] (com.apple.lsd[4696]) <Notice>: (com.apple.lsd) Idle-exit job was jettisoned. Will bypass throttle interval for next on-demand launch.
Jul  3 14:36:50 Damons-iPhone com.apple.launchd[1] (com.apple.lsd[4696]) <Error>: (com.apple.lsd) assertion failed: 11D201: launchd + 35933 [666E5F5B-36E7-3134-852E-A4BFEF07CD31]: 0x9
Jul  3 14:36:50 Damons-iPhone ****[4687] <Warning>: Received memory warning.
Jul  3 14:36:50 Damons-iPhone com.apple.launchd[1] (com.apple.nsnetworkd[4697]) <Notice>: (com.apple.nsnetworkd) Idle-exit job was jettisoned. Will bypass throttle interval for next on-demand launch.
Jul  3 14:36:50 Damons-iPhone com.apple.launchd[1] (com.apple.nsnetworkd[4697]) <Error>: (com.apple.nsnetworkd) assertion failed: 11D201: launchd + 35933 [666E5F5B-36E7-3134-852E-A4BFEF07CD31]: 0x9
Jul  3 14:36:50 Damons-iPhone com.apple.launchd[1] (com.apple.lsd[4698]) <Notice>: (com.apple.lsd) Idle-exit job was jettisoned. Will bypass throttle interval for next on-demand launch.
Jul  3 14:36:50 Damons-iPhone com.apple.launchd[1] (com.apple.lsd[4698]) <Error>: (com.apple.lsd) assertion failed: 11D201: launchd + 35933 [666E5F5B-36E7-3134-852E-A4BFEF07CD31]: 0x9
Jul  3 14:36:50 Damons-iPhone ****[4687] <Warning>: Received memory warning.
Jul  3 14:36:50 Damons-iPhone com.apple.launchd[1] (com.apple.lsd[4700]) <Notice>: (com.apple.lsd) Idle-exit job was jettisoned. Will bypass throttle interval for next on-demand launch.
Jul  3 14:36:50 Damons-iPhone com.apple.launchd[1] (com.apple.lsd[4700]) <Error>: (com.apple.lsd) assertion failed: 11D201: launchd + 35933 [666E5F5B-36E7-3134-852E-A4BFEF07CD31]: 0x9
Jul  3 14:36:51 Damons-iPhone com.apple.launchd[1] (com.apple.nsnetworkd[4699]) <Notice>: (com.apple.nsnetworkd) Idle-exit job was jettisoned. Will bypass throttle interval for next on-demand launch.
Jul  3 14:36:51 Damons-iPhone com.apple.launchd[1] (com.apple.nsnetworkd[4699]) <Error>: (com.apple.nsnetworkd) assertion failed: 11D201: launchd + 35933 [666E5F5B-36E7-3134-852E-A4BFEF07CD31]: 0x9
Jul  3 14:36:51 Damons-iPhone com.apple.launchd[1] (com.apple.lsd[4701]) <Notice>: (com.apple.lsd) Idle-exit job was jettisoned. Will bypass throttle interval for next on-demand launch.
Jul  3 14:36:51 Damons-iPhone com.apple.launchd[1] (com.apple.lsd[4701]) <Error>: (com.apple.lsd) assertion failed: 11D201: launchd + 35933 [666E5F5B-36E7-3134-852E-A4BFEF07CD31]: 0x9
Jul  3 14:36:51 Damons-iPhone com.apple.launchd[1] (com.apple.lsd[4703]) <Notice>: (com.apple.lsd) Idle-exit job was jettisoned. Will bypass throttle interval for next on-demand launch.
Jul  3 14:36:51 Damons-iPhone com.apple.launchd[1] (com.apple.lsd[4703]) <Error>: (com.apple.lsd) assertion failed: 11D201: launchd + 35933 [666E5F5B-36E7-3134-852E-A4BFEF07CD31]: 0x9
Jul  3 14:36:51 Damons-iPhone com.apple.launchd[1] (com.apple.nsnetworkd[4702]) <Notice>: (com.apple.nsnetworkd) Idle-exit job was jettisoned. Will bypass throttle interval for next on-demand launch.
Jul  3 14:36:51 Damons-iPhone com.apple.launchd[1] (com.apple.nsnetworkd[4702]) <Error>: (com.apple.nsnetworkd) assertion failed: 11D201: launchd + 35933 [666E5F5B-36E7-3134-852E-A4BFEF07CD31]: 0x9
Jul  3 14:36:51 Damons-iPhone ****[4687] <Warning>: Received memory warning.
Jul  3 14:36:51 Damons-iPhone com.apple.launchd[1] (com.apple.lsd[4704]) <Notice>: (com.apple.lsd) Idle-exit job was jettisoned. Will bypass throttle interval for next on-demand launch.
Jul  3 14:36:51 Damons-iPhone com.apple.launchd[1] (com.apple.lsd[4704]) <Error>: (com.apple.lsd) assertion failed: 11D201: launchd + 35933 [666E5F5B-36E7-3134-852E-A4BFEF07CD31]: 0x9
Jul  3 14:36:51 Damons-iPhone ****[4687] <Warning>: Received memory warning.
Jul  3 14:36:51 Damons-iPhone com.apple.launchd[1] (com.apple.lsd[4706]) <Notice>: (com.apple.lsd) Idle-exit job was jettisoned. Will bypass throttle interval for next on-demand launch.
Jul  3 14:36:51 Damons-iPhone com.apple.launchd[1] (com.apple.lsd[4706]) <Error>: (com.apple.lsd) assertion failed: 11D201: launchd + 35933 [666E5F5B-36E7-3134-852E-A4BFEF07CD31]: 0x9
Jul  3 14:36:51 Damons-iPhone com.apple.launchd[1] (com.apple.nsnetworkd[4705]) <Notice>: (com.apple.nsnetworkd) Idle-exit job was jettisoned. Will bypass throttle interval for next on-demand launch.
Jul  3 14:36:51 Damons-iPhone com.apple.launchd[1] (com.apple.nsnetworkd[4705]) <Error>: (com.apple.nsnetworkd) assertion failed: 11D201: launchd + 35933 [666E5F5B-36E7-3134-852E-A4BFEF07CD31]: 0x9
Jul  3 14:36:51 Damons-iPhone com.apple.launchd[1] (com.apple.lsd[4708]) <Notice>: (com.apple.lsd) Idle-exit job was jettisoned. Will bypass throttle interval for next on-demand launch.
Jul  3 14:36:51 Damons-iPhone com.apple.launchd[1] (com.apple.lsd[4708]) <Error>: (com.apple.lsd) assertion failed: 11D201: launchd + 35933 [666E5F5B-36E7-3134-852E-A4BFEF07CD31]: 0x9
Jul  3 14:36:51 Damons-iPhone ****[4687] <Warning>: Received memory warning.
Jul  3 14:36:51 Damons-iPhone com.apple.launchd[1] (com.apple.lsd[4710]) <Notice>: (com.apple.lsd) Idle-exit job was jettisoned. Will bypass throttle interval for next on-demand launch.
Jul  3 14:36:51 Damons-iPhone com.apple.launchd[1] (com.apple.lsd[4710]) <Error>: (com.apple.lsd) assertion failed: 11D201: launchd + 35933 [666E5F5B-36E7-3134-852E-A4BFEF07CD31]: 0x9
Jul  3 14:36:51 Damons-iPhone ****[4687] <Warning>: Received memory warning.
Jul  3 14:36:51 Damons-iPhone com.apple.launchd[1] (com.apple.lsd[4711]) <Notice>: (com.apple.lsd) Idle-exit job was jettisoned. Will bypass throttle interval for next on-demand launch.
Jul  3 14:36:51 Damons-iPhone com.apple.launchd[1] (com.apple.lsd[4711]) <Error>: (com.apple.lsd) assertion failed: 11D201: launchd + 35933 [666E5F5B-36E7-3134-852E-A4BFEF07CD31]: 0x9
Jul  3 14:36:52 Damons-iPhone kernel[0] <Debug>: AppleH4CamIn::setPowerStateGated: 0
Jul  3 14:36:52 Damons-iPhone kernel[0] <Debug>: AppleH4CamIn::power_off_hardware
```

Comment: You need to call `dismissViewControllerAnimated` on the image picker, not `self`.

Comment: Tried that and it still crashes.

Comment: What crash? Your question never mentioned a crash. Why don't you post the code that actually attempts to dismiss the picker. And if you are getting a crash, post details about the crash.

Comment: edited post with relevent details

Comment: Could you please clarify what you mean when you are saying "current view" ?

Comment: I have a view controller that has been pushed onto the navigation stack, on that view I have a button I click on to open the image picker. When I click on use image, the camera picker view closes back out to the view I was originally on, and then that view closes.